# Looking for a single file C++ (or C) implementation of string to float/ double

Tags: c++

I'm trying to parse a string to a float/ double within an eosio smart contract, which is basically C++ compiled to Webassembly. For some reason, the standard functions for this do not work (stof, stod, strtof, strtod), which is a known problem (https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1682/convert-string-to-float-or-double)

So what I'm looking for is a single file string to float/ string to double implementation. I know of implementations like libstdc++ and libc++, but these all import various other files, and it would be very impractical for me to have to include potentially dozens of files just for a single function.

So the question is, do you know of any proper single file string to float implementations. Using other std functions is not a problem.

Comment: Afaik somewhere in the glibc sources ou can find it, here I would suggest a good start: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/atof.c

Comment: As we don't recommend "implementations" or [code fragments](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185) here, I assume you are asking for a library? Any concerns towards its license (to meet the one you're using for your code)?